Why there's an error "Cannot resolve method 'compareTo' in 'Object' while K extends Comparable has been specified explicitly at the class header?
package bstmap;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class BSTMap<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Map61B<K, V>{
    private static class Node <K, V>{
        private final K key;
        private final V value;
        private Node left;
        private Node right;

        private Node(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
        }
    }

    private Node root;
    private int size;

    public BSTMap() {
        root = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(K key) {
        Node current = root;
        while (current != null) {
            if (current.key.equals(key)) {
                return true;
            }
            if (current.key.compareTo(key) < 0) {
                current = current.right;
            } else {
                current = current.left;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

There is an error at "current.key.compareTo(key)".
I am not using a raw type as I am specifying the generic types used by the inner class i.e. Node <K, V> but why Java doesn't consider the key of Node of type K extending the Comparable interface? When using raw type it means that we are using a class without explicitly specifying the type arguments for the generic type variables but over here all was specified nicely.

"Node current = root;" - This is a raw type.

Ohh so I guess I must explicitly specify that Node uses generic type K, V when creating a variable of type Node? And this means that the left and right at the Node class is also a raw type right?

"Ohh so I guess I must explicitly specify that Node uses generic type K, V when creating a variable of type Node?" - not when calling, but when defining, i.e. private Node root; -> private Node<K, V> root;. --- "*And this means that the left and right at the Node class is also a raw type right?` - yes. They should all be typed.
